# How to load a unique when.js file in html

Tags: javascript, promise, boilerplate

For now, this setup is working, but I wish to improve it.

I use `when.js` with this

**apps.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>When experiments</title>

    <script charset="UTF-8" data-main="./apps/js/require-minimum" src="./apps/js/require-2.1.9.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.promisejs.org/polyfills/promise-6.0.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        require( [ 'when' ], function( when ) {
           ...
        } );

    </script>
</head>
<body id="body">...
```

where the file `require-minium.js` contains:

```
require.config( {
    paths: {
        "jquery": "jquery-1.10.2",
        "underscore": "lodash.dev",
        "when": "when",
        "backbone": "backbone"
    },
    shim: {
        "underscore": {
            exports: "_"
        },
        "jquery": {
            "deps": [ "when", "jquery" ],
            exports: "$"
        },
        "backbone": {
            "deps": [ "underscore", "jquery" ],
            "exports": "Backbone"
        },
        "when": {
            "exports": "when"
        }

    }
} );
```

To load `when.js` successfully, I had to create the lib directory in my `apps/js/` to let `when.js` load its "modules" when needed.

Is there a way to have only a single `when.js` library file or is it my setup that is not correctly installed ?

Comment: I'm confused about what you're asking. Perhaps posting your require.js config would help clarify things?

Comment: I just wish to have one single when.js file, but it failed until I copied the full lib directory into apps/js/.